# How to Check FormData is Blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```js
var kdata = new FormData();
         
        $('#tblAttachment tr').each(function(i, row){
            
            // reference all the stuff you need first
            var row = $(row);
            var File = row.find('input[name*="file"]')
            var file = File.get(0).files[0];
            
            if(file != null && checkFileExtension(File.val())){
                kdata.append('file-' + i.toString(), file);
            } 
        });
```

I want to Check that "kdata" has been initialized or not how to do that

Thanks

Comment: Define *"kdata" has been initialized*.

Comment: want to check if condition has been excuted or not .. b/c i want to send request to server for uploading only if kdata have some fileUpload controls in it

Answer (score 2):

eazy way:

```
let fd= new FormData();
console.log(!!fd.entries().next().value); // false
fd.append("foo", 'xxx')
console.log(!!fd.entries().next().value); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if `kdata` is not null or undefined which if the first line runs, it shouldn't be: `if(kdata)`

But if you are looking for a particular property of `kdata`, you should check that property directly: `if (kdata.property-you-want)`.  If these lines are in this order, with nothing in between, then the only property that will be on the object `kdata` is the method(`append()`) which its constructor initializes it to have.

You must then either manually append `DOMString` Name and Values to your `kdata` object (see reference linked below), or initialize it with an `HTMLFormElement`like so:

`var kdata = new FormData(HTML-form-element-you-want-kdata-to-be);`

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData